# I got the "AttributeError: 'OutStream' object has no attribute 'buffer'" when i run the below python code that are from w3school in the google colab

Tags: python, object, attributes, buffer

Here I mention the code that I saw in the w3school.

```
    # w3school code
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

health_data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=0, sep=",")

health_data.plot(x ='Average_Pulse', y='Calorie_Burnage', kind='line'),
plt.ylim(ymin=0, ymax=400)
plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=150)

plt.show()

#Two  lines to make our compiler able to draw:
plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

And I got the error (AttributeError: 'OutStream' object has no attribute 'buffer') if I performed the above operation on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/imbikramsaha/indian-gdp) dataset in google colab via using the below code.

```
 #Three lines to make our compiler able to draw:
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

health_data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/India_GDP_Data.csv", header=0, sep=",")

health_data.plot(x ='Year', y='GDP_In_Billion_USD', kind='line'),
plt.ylim(ymin=0, ymax=400)
plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=150)

plt.show()

#Two  lines to make our compiler able to draw:
plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on W3schools as well!

Use `matplotlib inline` in you notebook like this:

```py
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.plot()

plt.show()

sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming so late but I feel it may help someone else later.
I got the same code from w3school fixed in Jupyter Notebook by doing the following things:

1. Remove matplotlib.use('Agg')
2. add %matplotlib inline
3. Change plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer) to plt.savefig("mygraph.png")
   Find the working good below.

   ```
   %matplotlib inline
   import sys
   import matplotlib


   import pandas as pd
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   health_data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=0, sep=",")

   health_data.plot(x ='Average_Pulse', y='Calorie_Burnage', kind='line'),
   plt.ylim(ymin=0, ymax=400)
   plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=150)

   plt.show()

   #Two  lines to make our compiler able to draw:
   plt.savefig("mygraph.png")
   sys.stdout.flush()
   ```